# Multiple Distinct Values with SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have a table which Data is like

```
userID      name        amount   Date
     1        mark        20     22-10
     1        mark        30     22-10
     2        kane        50     22-12  
     2        kane        60     22-12
     3        mike        60     22-10
```

Date is Unique with combination of userID + Username + Date

but as its more then 100k records there maybe duplicate date records but wither other user ids and names not with

**now i want Output like**

```
userID      name        amount    Date
     1        mark        50      22-10
     2        kane        110     22-12 
     3        mike        60      22-10
```

if i try group By with id,name,sum(amount),date it returns multiple rows and answer incorrect

**i have tried various combination of distict and SUM etc etc but not succeeded 
any Solution 
Thanks**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You typically use a [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) to aggregate one or more fields by one or more other fields.

```
SELECT  userID, Name, SUM(amount), MIN(date)
FROM    YourTable
GROUP BY
        userID, Name
```

From MSDN: [Aggregate functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258901%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> Aggregate functions perform a calculation on a set of values and
>   return a single value. With the exception of COUNT, aggregate
>   functions ignore null values. Aggregate functions are often used with
>   the GROUP BY clause of the SELECT statement.

some typical aggregate functions are

- SUM
- MIN
- AVG
- ...

From MSDN: [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

> Groups a selected set of rows into a set of summary rows by the values
>   of one or more columns or expressions in SQL Server 2008 R2. One row
>   is returned for each group. Aggregate functions in the SELECT clause
>    list provide information about each group instead of
>   individual rows.

Comment: @user353600 - You have to make a choice here on what date you want for each row and use an aggregate function on the date. For your given example, it really doesn't matter since all date's (for each group) are the same. You can simply add `MIN(Date)` to the select statement.

Comment: -1 : for being overly verbose and a smart-alec.  No, wait, that's me.  +1 for being not only correct, but actually quite informative in your answer...

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  userId, name, sum(amount) as amount
from
  table
group by
  userId, name
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want `DISTINCT` here, but rather `GROUP BY` with the aggregate `SUM()`

```
SELECT 
  userID,
  name,
  SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM tbl
GROUP BY userID, name
```